# jquery datepicker allow a specific text to be entered or selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I want either the user can select a particular date or it can be filled up with say 'xyz'. I have tried using `constrainInput = false` but that allow user to enter anything. I only want the user can write or select only 'xyz'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test the date input value:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    constrainInput: false,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
}).on("change", function () {
    // Accepts xyz as the value
    if ($(this).val() == "xyz")
        return true;

    // Accepts just valid dates as the value
    var comp = $(this).val().split('/');
    var m = parseInt(comp[0], 10);
    var d = parseInt(comp[1], 10);
    var y = parseInt(comp[2], 10);
    var date = new Date(y,m-1,d);

    if (date.getFullYear() == y && date.getMonth() + 1 == m && date.getDate() == d)
        return true;

    alert("Wrong");        
});
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/sFBn2/9/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select only one day, why not disable the input on the field and use only the datepicker with the day selection limited only to it?

Fot the disabled field use the attribute `readonly` of the input, for the datepicker day limitation use the [`beforeShowDay`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) function.

HTML:

```
<input type='text' id='foo' readonly='true'>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#foo').datepicker({
    constrainInput: false,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var today=new Date();
        if (date.getDate() == today.getDate()) {
            return [true, ''];
        }
        return [false, ''];
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/qdBkZ/